# Can I pool these groups?

Tags: pooling

So I am not completely sure whether I can pool my groups or not to compare them, or if it would be better to compare them pair-wise. The purpose of this comparison is to test the efficacy of my stress protocol. Here is my experiment design:

In my first data set I have three different types of subjects divided in three groups: 1, 2, 3.
In the other part of my data set I have the same type of subjects from the groups 1, 2, 3 but they have been stressed (not the same subjects, but same type). So their groups are called 1s, 2s, 3s.

Would it be okay for me to pool group 1, 2 ,3 into one group, and then pool my group 1s,2s, 3s into one group and compare the two pooled groups using a t-test/MannWhitneyU?

Comment: Might be more revealing to do three MW tests: 1 vs 1s, 2 vs 2s, 3 vs 3s.  That way you have a chance of of picking up interaction btw Types and Stress. // One MW test of No Stress vs Stress, pooling types, might be misleading. (I'd do that only after verifying that the three MW tests give somewhat similar results.) // If you do any such 'pooling' you need to make sure to disclose that in stat analysis section of your report. // If data aprx normal, you might do a two-factor ANOVA with factors Type & Stress, with Interaction.

Comment: Thank you so much! That does indeed make more sense. My data is "unfortunately not normal". And I believe you are correct in that it would be safer with pair-wise tests than pooling, or even running a Kruskal-Wallis for multiple comparison? Either way, thank you again for you response!